# How are width values handed down in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Currently I am struggling to correctly size wpf controls. Therefore I'd like to know how dimensions like width are handed down the hierarchy in an xaml file. What happens for example if a width value is overwritten by a set MinWidth value? How and when are the other elements resized and what events are involved? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi and welcome. A clear question, but this seems like something you could find with google and specifically msdn. have you looked there?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout

Comment: Hi, yes you are right it is a very fundamental question. I did some research on those sites already and came across some descriptions like:
"The return value of this property is always the same as any value that was set to it. In contrast, the value of the ActualWidth may vary. The layout may have rejected the suggested size for some reason. [...]

Comment: Also, the layout system itself works asynchronously relative to the property system set of Width and may not have processed that particular sizing property change yet.". Now that let me to ask here since I do not know what is meant by "not processed yet" and "for some reason" specifically. It feels like updates such as window resizing is beeing handled by different threads that might overwrite the same properties. I am interested in what the actual order of operations is here. Can one maybe debug that?

Answer (score 0):

There is many topics in this question, it's looks like you're looking all information or manual about sizing controls.

For the first question basically a width property for a control is only for that control, not for the child controls. The layout (for example a Grid) of the controls plays an important role because sometimes they stretch, center or moves the controls, but a fixed number width works most of the time on the control you want to resize.

About MinWidth is not overwritten by Width property, yo can set less width of MinWidth, the value is stored but the control will be drawed with the MinWidth value because is higher in that case.

About Events, there is an Event called "SizeChanged" that triggers when the Height or Width is changed, but it's in execution time, there is no event that are triggering in design mode.

Try to practice with Grids, research about layouts like Grids, Canvas, StackPanels, etc. Maybe there is your answer. Canvas let you draw free, but I don't recomend get used to use canvas.